# Event not triggered for UIButton in UIView in UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

In my UITableViewCell I have an UIImageView with a UIButton.

Here my [code](http://pastebin.com/CSNuFEdh)

My problem is that each time I try to click on the UIButton the UITableViewCell is triggered by the TouchUpInside event and not the UIBUtton.

Can you please help me?

Comment: The UIView class must be derived from UItableViewCell, and use the method `addContentView` of table view cell to add your elements to the table view cell

Comment: Do you mean [cell.contentView addSubview:] ?

Comment: The link you provided has no code!

Answer (score 0):

This is my code.. here I use a `UIButton` inside the `UITableViewCell` and it works perfectly for me..  Hope this will help you..

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ChildList";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    itsChildContactsTableView = tableView;
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                       reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // we need a view to place our labels on.
    UIView *aTableCellContentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];



    CGRect contentRect = aTableCellContentView.bounds;

    CGFloat boundsX = contentRect.origin.x;
    CGRect frame;

    frame = CGRectMake(boundsX + 10, 8, 200, 20);



    UIButton *aCallButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [aCallButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"call.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [aCallButton addTarget:self action:@selector(dialNumber:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [aCallButton  setTag:[indexPath row]];

    frame = CGRectMake(210, 14, 35, 35);
    aCallButton.frame = frame;

    UIButton *aEmailButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [aEmailButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mail.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [aEmailButton addTarget:self action:@selector(eMailContact:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


    [aEmailButton  setTag:[indexPath row]];

    frame = CGRectMake(250, 14, 35, 35);

    aEmailButton.frame = frame;
    aTableCellContentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:aCallButton];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:aEmailButton];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:aTableCellContentView];
    [aTableCellContentView release];
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if your UITableViewCell has a customer height(not the default 44.0f)。 if so, you should set the code like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellID = @"cellID";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellID];
        cell.contentView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.width, [self tableView:tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]);
        // add a UIButton that you create
    }
    return cell;
}
```

the reason for this problem is the cell.contentView.size is default (320.f, 44.0f), if your button is over the rect, then the button could not accept the event, so you should set the cell.contentView.frame yourself, like i do the code。

Good Luck。

Comment: Please done't post the exact same answer to multiple questions: it's either not a good fit for all or the questions are duplicates which should be flagged/closed as such.